# insert a value to caml query from the list

Tags: sharepoint-online

when a user is trying to insert an item that already exist in the list - I want to know about it and an email will be send to me. 
so I want to write a caml query that will contain the value the user trying to insert in the list and will compare to other items in the list.
the query:

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name='Name' />
     <Value Type='Text'>[The value the user insert in the list]</Value>
  </Eq>
```

but how can I insert to the value of what the user wrote?

is this possible? how?
thank you!

Comment: can u explain more? you want to insert the value into the list ?

Answer (score 4):

I think you would be better of if you would set `Enforce Unique Value` as `true` for the required columns.

P.S. You can do that by going to the `List Settings -> Select the column -> Enforce unique values as True`

Answer (score 4):

You can use SharePoint Event Receivers.. [ItemAdding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadding%28v=office.14%29.aspx) is the event receiver you are looking for..

Please have a look at:

[Creating SharePoint 2010 Event Receivers in Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252010%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: I can't use the Event Receiver: ItemAdding, I use SP Online.

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you mean but if you mean how to query using the user value than you just have to write it this way

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name='Name' />
     <Value Type='Text'>"+ [The value the user insert in the list] + "</Value>
  </Eq>
```

Comment: I will explain more: when a user is trying to insert an item that already exist in the list - I want to know about it and an email will be send to me. so I want to write a caml query that will contain the value the user trying to insert in the list and will compare to other items in the list.

Comment: you perform the above query and take viewfield as Name and compare the item with your value. if its equal than give an alert message and write a logic to send email

Comment: then Event Receivers -as suggested by @Arsalan- are the way

Comment: @MdMazzotti  event receiver is the best approach if it was SP on premise. But he has tagged SP online.Is there any way to send email from event recievers in SP online?.Also is it recommended to write Event receivers for online as it will be sandbox code

Comment: @Unnie you're right, I didn't notice the tag. By the way, I think you meant "it is *not* recommended to.."

Comment: @user25290 so your goal is to check for duplicate entries based on a certain column? Is it?

Comment: yes, and if this item is already exist - an email will be send to me and will not be added.

Comment: @user25290 Please  update your full functionality in question.

Answer (score 1):

Forget CAML query in this case. Use a workflow instead. Setup a workflow on the list that will trigger every time a new item is added.

In the workflow you can setup logic which checks if the newly added items Title property equals an existing one and then send the e-mail accordingly.

This can easily be done using SharePoint Designer, which is compatible with SharePoint Online.